# How to prevent Shiny `nav_menu()` from overflowing?

Tags: py-shiny

Working in Python Shiny - having this issue with the `ui.nav_menu()` function where the items overflow beyond the screen. Tried adjusting the `align` parameter to both `'left'` and `'right'` but that didn't resolve it.

```
ui.nav_menu(
    'Help',
    ui.nav('Instructions', templates.template_help_instructions()),
    ui.nav('Runtime', templates.template_help_runtime()),
    ui.nav('Feedback', templates.template_help_feedback()),
    ui.nav('Contact', templates.template_help_contact())
)
```

The output looks something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwJZQ.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve it?